# Как реализовать декоративный элемент?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать декоративные полоски таким образом: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть CSS свойство `border-image`. Примеры можно посмотреть тут:
[w3schools.com: CSS border-image Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такие границы для нужного вам элемента возможно реализовать с помощью `repeating-linear-gradient`. Пример:

```css
div {
width: 100%;
height: 50vh;
background: gainsboro;
border-top: 8px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
border-image: 
repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,
      red,
      red 20px,
      transparent 20px,
      transparent 23px,
      blue 23px,
      blue 43px,
      transparent 43px,
      transparent 46px);
border-image-slice: 8;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```